# Assigning a mathematical string expression to double variable

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a mathematical expression in string form like:

```
string strExpression = "10+100+Math.Sin(90)";
```

I want to simply assign this expression (at run time) to a `float` variable (say `result`), so that it becomes the following code statement:

```
float result = 10+100+Math.Sin(90);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile the expression within a syntactically correct code block. See http://devreminder.wordpress.com/net/net-framework-fundamentals/c-dynamic-math-expression-evaluation/ as an example.

Edit: Or alternatively write your own expression parser if the expression is going to be VERY simple (I wouldn't recommend this though)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) to dynamically make a class with a method that you can run, if you don't want to write your own parser but rather use C# which you allready know..